# Codeigniter delete function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to build a simple delete function in my project to delete data from a table. I .can't figure out why it is not working. I used the codeigniter user guide to help me out with this. I am getting an error and don't know why. Here is my controller, model and view for the delete:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$id

**Model**

```
function delete()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $tables = array('info', 'info2');
    $this->db->where('id', 1);
    $this->db->delete($tables);

}
```

**controller**

```
 function del($tables){


if((int)$tables > 0){
          $this->info_model->delete($tables);
}

$data = $this->info_model->delete();
$data['query'] = $this->result_model->delete();

$this->load->view('info_view',$data);    
 }
```

**view**

```
//this line gives me the error

 <td><?php echo anchor('info_controller/del' . $row->id,'Delete')?> </td>
```

**EDIT**

I used this tutorial to make this

```
http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Form-Centralizing-$data-P291.html
```

Comment: your model functions doesnt have any parameters accepting, then how its posible to call `$this->info_model->delete($tables);` ?

Comment: put condition like if isset($row->id) and check. This variable is not existing

Comment: i daunt know i am very green to this can u explain more about this

Comment: $this->load->database(); $this->load->model('YourModelName');

Comment: The following might be helpful for you: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller Load your model like this

```
$this->load->model('deletion_model');
```

Then call the method of the deletion_model

```
$this->deletion_model->delete($id);
```

Make sure you load the model.

after that i suggest you pass value of id as string.

```
$this->db->where('id', '1');
```

OR

use the variable supplied to this function if you are not using static values

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
```

Please read the guide properly

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#delete

You can also retrieve the id of the record for deletion by using

```
$id=$this->uri->segment(3); // depending on which segment the id is
```

Answer (score -1):

1. I do not see any `$row` object in your controller, although you use it in your view: `$row->id`
2. Your model is not returning anything.
3. If you delete a specified row, `$object->id` will cease to exist.
4. The link in your view it states that you want to show a delete link, but you use that view in the controller that deals with the actual delete action.

Edit:
Because you try to iterate in your view through query results, `$data['query']` from your controller should point to a select statement.

Comment: i do have  <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>  <?php endforeach; ?> in my view forgot to include that

Comment: Explaining the down vote it would be nice. @user2143150 see the updated answer.

Comment: tnx for your help but i am still not understanding can u use more examples

Comment: @user2143150 In your controller assign query results from select statemment to `$data['query']` like `$data['query'] = $this->db->get('info')` so that in view you can iterate with `foreach($query as $row)`. As a side note: If you do not understand something from an answer, you do not down vote, you just request for clarification.